# How do I create a bar chart with categorical variables ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data looks like this:

```
structure(list(Year = c(1986L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 
1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 1994L, 
1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
2004L, 2005L, 2006L), Commodity.Code = c(84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 
84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 
85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L), Trade.Value = c(152775, 
2832605, 18315000, 25698163, 27913535, 30960755, 39638469, 47361219, 
48195570, 989056362, 2561299092, 2757388123, 2921517723, 3445065950, 
81496, 3621489, 42467420, 101764359, 121149310, 155909559, 124826429, 
132251188, 239727925, 349458661, 506121578, 768955783, 1034644162
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -27L))
```

Where `Year` is the year, `Commodity.Code` is commodity code of a product, and `Trade.Vaue` is the USD value of the commodity in that year. How can I create a bar chart with `Year` on the x-axis, and `Trade.Value` is on the y axis, and the fill is the `Commodity.Code`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
library(ggplot2)

your_data <- structure(list(Year = c(1986L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 
                                     1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 1994L, 
                                     1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
                                     2004L, 2005L, 2006L), Commodity.Code = c(84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 
                                                                              84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 
                                                                              85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L), Trade.Value = c(152775, 
                                                                                                                                                 2832605, 18315000, 25698163, 27913535, 30960755, 39638469, 47361219, 
                                                                                                                                                 48195570, 989056362, 2561299092, 2757388123, 2921517723, 3445065950, 
                                                                                                                                                 81496, 3621489, 42467420, 101764359, 121149310, 155909559, 124826429, 
                                                                                                                                                 132251188, 239727925, 349458661, 506121578, 768955783, 1034644162
                                                                              )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -27L))

ggplot(data = your_data, aes(x = Year, y = Trade.Value, fill = factor(Commodity.Code))) +
  geom_col() +
  labs(title = "Commodity Trade Value Over the Years",
       x = "Year",
       y = "Trade Value",
       fill = "Commodity Code")
```

?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(Year = c(1986L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 
1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 1994L, 
1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
2004L, 2005L, 2006L), Commodity.Code = c(84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 
84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 
85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L), Trade.Value = c(152775, 
2832605, 18315000, 25698163, 27913535, 30960755, 39638469, 47361219, 
48195570, 989056362, 2561299092, 2757388123, 2921517723, 3445065950, 
81496, 3621489, 42467420, 101764359, 121149310, 155909559, 124826429, 
132251188, 239727925, 349458661, 506121578, 768955783, 1034644162
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -27L))

df %>% 
  mutate(Commodity.Code = factor(Commodity.Code)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Year, Trade.Value, fill = Commodity.Code)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: How do I add ticks so that it shows every year from 1994 to 2006, and also limit years to only from 1994 onwards? Thank you.

Comment: Simply add  `+ scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1994, NA), breaks = seq(1985, 2006, 1))`.

Comment: Please mark the question as solved/give credit to the answer so anybody can see the problem is solved.